# TypeScript function generic parameter whitch is composed not contains expected field

Tags: typescript

How can I pass document composed like in example to function with generic parameter?

```
type WithId = {
    _id?: string;
};

type DocumentWithId<D> = D & WithId;

type Contact = {
    title: string;
};

type ContactWithId = DocumentWithId<Contact>;

function saveDocument<D extends DocumentWithId<any>>(document: D) {
    if (document._id) {
        console.log('Update', document);
    } else {
        console.log('Create', document);
    }
}
```

When I run this code, compile error occured:

```
Property '_id' does not exist on type 'D'.
```

[Run example here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=17&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBA6glsAFgSQCZQLxQN4CgoFQD6cqA-AFxQDOwATnAHYDmA3LgL7u6iRQAiAewDGAVwC2ERsHhI0AHn4A%20TAKgAyWAhSpuvaAGFB0gIbDgqvISjAEAGwhVaDFuy64e4Q8eBmZ2tFUhMUlpWR15I1NzJW4AM1FGczhjGwhaBX4oCAAPYClUagERCSl-OVR5E0YQJSUAClQS0OAqfgBKHHxCODioRuaygDoSVE6ra0JhY2pBByG7QWZ6gANkLLi4OwdUKgASbCaQ4dGOFfb2aw5OXCA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
type DocumentWithId<any> = any & WithId; //Becomes any that's why it's not working

function saveDocument<D extends DocumentWithId<unknown>>(document: D) {
    if (document._id) {
        console.log('Update', document);
    } else {
        console.log('Create', document);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're already passing the generic parameter to `type DocumentWithId<D> = D & WithId;`, so there's no need to specify the generic parameter of the function.

```
type WithId = {
    _id?: string;
};

type DocumentWithId<D> = D & WithId;

type Contact = {
    title: string;
};

type ContactWithId = DocumentWithId<Contact>;

function testId<D>(document: DocumentWithId<D>) {
    if (document._id) {
        console.log(`ID filled: ${document._id}`);
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA6glsAFgSQCZQLxQN4CgoFQD6cqA-AFxQDOwATnAHYDmA3LgL7u6iRQAiAewDGAVwC2ERsHhI0AHn4A+TAKgAyWAhSpuvaAGFB0gIbDgqvISjAEAGwhVaDFuy64e4Q8eBmZ2tFUhMUlpWR15I1NzJW4AM1FGczhjGwhaBWUAClQRCSlgKmD8sIDURSUAShx8Qjg4qBy80OAAOhJUaqtrQmFjakEHVrtBZiyAA2R+KDi4OwdUKgASbFyQgvbSDnHK9msOTlwgA)